# cocoa/iPad How do I keep a UIButton clickable when its alpha == 0?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uibutton

When I set a UIButton's alpha to 0, it behaves as if it isn't enabled. I've checked and, even though the button does remain enabled (though invisible (but not hidden, I checked that as well)), it ceases to work.

Is there any way to keep it clickable even when its alpha is 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to put another UIButton on top of it with it's UIButtonStyle set to "custom" and just leave it as it is, except of adding your IBAction to it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the original button's type to custom. Too simple!

Comment: what.. isn't this what the hidden property is for? pretty big assumption the API makes..

Answer (score 11):

UIButtonStyle set to "custom". And instead of alpha 0, you need to set background to 'clear color'.